# проблема с получением данных xml файла

Tags: python, xml, xmlparser

Подскажите в чем может быть связана проблема:

дан следующий xml файл:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<СообщОтказ_115ФЗ>
<СлужЧасть>
  <ВерсияФормата>1.2</ВерсияФормата>
  <ДатаСообщения>10/12/2018</ДатаСообщения>
  <ТелОператор>8(499) 237-33-32</ТелОператор>
  <ЭлектроннаяПочта>svc_550P@cbr.ru</ЭлектроннаяПочта>
</СлужЧасть>
<ИнформЧасть>

    <СведФЛИП>    
      <ФИОФЛИП>    
        <Фам>Массссссс</Фам>    
        <Имя>Насссссс</Имя>    
        <Отч>Дсссссссс</Отч>    
      </ФИОФЛИП>    
      <ИННФЛИП></ИННФЛИП>    
      <СведДокУдЛичн>    
        <ВидДокКод>21</ВидДокКод>    
        <ВидДокНаименование>Паспорт гражданина Российской Федерации (для гражданина Российской Федерации, достигшего 14 лет)</ВидДокНаименование>    
        <СерияДок>8888</СерияДок>    
        <НомДок>7777777</НомДок>    
        <ДатВыдачиДок>01/10/2000</ДатВыдачиДок>    
        <КемВыданДок>Мухоршибирский РОВД республики Бурятия</КемВыданДок>    
        <КодПодр>032-016</КодПодр>    
      </СведДокУдЛичн>    
      <ДатаРождения>10/00/1900</ДатаРождения>    
      <МестоРожд>    
        <КодОКСМ>643</КодОКСМ>    
        <СтранаНаименование>РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ</СтранаНаименование>    
        <КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>81</КодСубъектаПоОКАТО>    
        <Район>МУХОРШИБИРСКИЙ Р-Н</Район>    
        <Пункт>ЦОЛГА С</Пункт>    
      </МестоРожд>    
      <КодОКСМ>643</КодОКСМ>    
      <СтранаНаименование>РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ</СтранаНаименование>    
      <ПризнакПубЛицо>0</ПризнакПубЛицо>    
    </СведФЛИП>
    </Участник>
  </Раздел2>
```

Пытаюсь распарсить при помощи следующего кода:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

with open("cbr_fio.xml", 'rb') as f:

    doc = minidom.parse(f)
    root = doc.getElementsByTagName("СведФЛИП")
    result = []
    name = {}
    for el in root:
        if el.getElementsByTagName('ФИОФЛИП'):
            name['FIO'] = f"{el.getAttribute('Фам')} {el.getAttribute('Имя')} {el.getAttribute('Отч')}"

            for data in root:
                if el.getElementsByTagName('СведДокУдЛичн'):
                    name['PassType'] = el.getAttribute('ВидДокНаименование')
                    name['PassNumber'] = f"{el.getAttribute('СерияДок')} {el.getAttribute('НомДок')}"

        result.append(name)
    print(result)
```

Но в итоге выдает пустые значения

```
[{'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '}, {'FIO': '  ', 'PassType': '', 'PassNumber': ' '},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в примере xml проставить все закрывающие теги

```
import xmltodict
with open("cbr_fio.xml", 'rb') as f:
    o_dict = xmltodict.parse(f.read())

import json
print(json.dumps(o_dict , indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

out

```
{
  "СообщОтказ_115ФЗ": {
    "СлужЧасть": {
      "ВерсияФормата": "1.2",
      "ДатаСообщения": "10/12/2018",
      "ТелОператор": "8(499) 237-33-32",
      "ЭлектроннаяПочта": "svc_550P@cbr.ru"
    },
    "ИнформЧасть": {
      "Раздел2": {
        "Участник": {
          "СведФЛИП": {
            "ФИОФЛИП": {
              "Фам": "Массссссс",
              "Имя": "Насссссс",
              "Отч": "Дсссссссс"
            },
            "ИННФЛИП": null,
            "СведДокУдЛичн": {
              "ВидДокКод": "21",
              "ВидДокНаименование": "Паспорт гражданина Российской Федерации (для гражданина Российской Федерации, достигшего 14 лет)",
              "СерияДок": "8888",
              "НомДок": "7777777",
              "ДатВыдачиДок": "01/10/2000",
              "КемВыданДок": "Мухоршибирский РОВД республики Бурятия",
              "КодПодр": "032-016"
            },
            "ДатаРождения": "10/00/1900",
            "МестоРожд": {
              "КодОКСМ": "643",
              "СтранаНаименование": "РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ",
              "КодСубъектаПоОКАТО": "81",
              "Район": "МУХОРШИБИРСКИЙ Р-Н",
              "Пункт": "ЦОЛГА С"
            },
            "КодОКСМ": "643",
            "СтранаНаименование": "РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ",
            "ПризнакПубЛицо": "0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Фам`, `Имя` и `Отч` - не атрибуты тега `ФИОФЛИП`, а дочерние теги. Попробуйте так

```
def first(items):
    try:
        return items[0]
    except (IndexError, TypeError):
        return None

def get_text(node):
    return ''.join(n.data for n in get getattr(node, 'childNodes', []) if n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE)

def get_child_text(parent, name):
    return get_text(first(parent.getElementsByTagName(name)))


name['FIO'] = ' '.join(get_child_text(el, i) for i in ['Фам', 'Имя', 'Отч'])
```

Comment: К сожалениею, проблема не решилась либо ошибка out of range либо DOM Element: Фам at 0x7f41ad83a9c8> :(

Comment: по исправленному коду выдает ошибку TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Element found

Comment: Проверьте новый вариант. Добавил проверку на наличие дочернего элемента и функцию извлечения текста из тега.

Comment: Увы :(((Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cbr_xml.py", line 32, in <module>
    name['FIO'] = ' '.join(get_child_text(el, i) for i in ['Фам', 'Имя', 'Отч'])
  File "cbr_xml.py", line 32, in <genexpr>
    name['FIO'] = ' '.join(get_child_text(el, i) for i in ['Фам', 'Имя', 'Отч'])
  File "cbr_xml.py", line 26, in get_child_text
    return get_text(first(parent.getElementsByTagName(name)))
  File "cbr_xml.py", line 23, in get_text
    return ''.join(n.data for n in nodes or [] if n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE)
TypeError: 'Element' object is not iterable

Comment: Исправил. Проверьте.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, теперь все заработало!